# Por que me da Null Exception?

Tags: java, método, nullpointerexception

Mi método es el siguiente:

```
public boolean addJugador(String nombre){
    boolean add=true;
    Jugador j= new Jugador(nombre);
        if(nombre!=mesa[jugadoresActuales].getNombre()){   

            mesa[jugadoresActuales]= j;
            jugadoresActuales++;
        }else{
        add=false;
        }

      return add;
}
```

El métedo `getNombre` es:

```
public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
```

El constructor de jugador es

```
public Jugador(String nombre){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    manoJugador=new Carta[MAXCARTAS];
    cartasActuales=0;
```

Jugadores actuales esta inicializado a 0.
Mesa es un array de tipo jugador que guarda jugadores que se añaden, y jugadores actuales es el numero de jugadores que hay.
No entiendo en que momento estoy apuntando a null, alguna idea?

Comment: Añade el constructor de `Jugador` también para ver como lo tienes hecho. Y `jugadoresActuales`, dónde la declaras, que valor tiene?

Comment: Edita la publicación y añade allí el código del constructor

Comment: @iHack [Actualiza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/117240/edit) tu pregunta con el código, no lo añadas como comentario. Añade el stacktrace, de paso, y las clases que usas

Comment: @iHack Añade tambien dónde declaras y llenas `mesa` para ver cómo estás insertando los datos allí.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando es el primer jugador el que añades, jugadoresActuales es igual a 0, con lo cual, si haces la comparación:

```
if(nombre!=mesa[jugadoresActuales].getNombre()){...}
```

es normal que te de un NullPointerException ya que intentas acceder a mesa[0] que es nulo.

Lo que deberías hacer es, si es el primer jugador añadirlo al array directamente y sino lo es, entonces si que haces tu comparación por nombre:

```
public boolean addJugador(String nombre){
    boolean add=true;
    Jugador j= new Jugador(nombre);
    if(jugadoresActuales==0){    //Si no hay jugadores lo añadimos
        mesa[jugadoresActuales]= j;
        jugadoresActuales++;
    }else if(nombre!=mesa[jugadoresActuales].getNombre()){   
        mesa[jugadoresActuales]= j;
        jugadoresActuales++;
    }else{
    add=false;
}

  return add;
}
```

Comment: da error en la linea en la que se usa el metodo getNombre

Comment: has inicializado el array mesa? en getNombre no veo como te puede dar la excepcion ahí. Depura el código y mira en qué línea te está dando el error y si es al introducir el primer jugador o el resto

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estás intentando comprobar si existe un jugador sin haber jugadores en el Array `mesa`.

Debes añadir una comprobación mirando si el `array = null` o si no tiene valores para añadir directamente el jugador y no te de el `NullException`:

```
public boolean addJugador(String nombre){
    boolean add=true;
    Jugador j= new Jugador(nombre);
    if (mesa != null && mesa.length != 0){
        if(nombre!=mesa[jugadoresActuales].getNombre()){   

            mesa[jugadoresActuales]= j;
            jugadoresActuales++;
        }else{
        add=false;
        }
    }else{
        //El array es null o no tiene valores, por lo tanto no existen jugadores y éste no va a existir, se añade
        mesa[jugadoresActuales]= j;
        jugadoresActuales++;
    }
      return add;
}
```

Comment: sigue dando el mismo error, creo que esta en el getNombre

Comment: @iHack Pon en la pregunta como declaras `mesa` para poder ver si viene de ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en este código funciona bien, sólo que se pueden ingresar duplicados de String, si no te sirve veo de adentrarme un poco más. lo hice un poco en el aire.

```
public class ControladorJugadores {

int jugadoresActuales = 0;
static Jugador[] mesa = new Jugador[3];

public boolean addJugador(String nombre) {
    boolean add = false;

    Jugador jugador = new Jugador(nombre);
    mesa[jugadoresActuales] = jugador;

    /* Agregamos acá los jugadores al array */

    if (nombre == mesa[jugadoresActuales].getNombre() && mesa[jugadoresActuales].getNombre() != null) {
        jugadoresActuales++;
        add = true;
    } else {
        add = false;
    }
    return add;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ControladorJugadores mj = new ControladorJugadores();
    System.out.println("Agregando a " + mj.addJugador("Marcelo"));
    System.out.println("Agregando a " + mj.addJugador("Batistuta"));
    System.out.println("Agregando a " + mj.addJugador("Verinky"));

    System.out.println("Esta es la cantidad total al momento: " + mj.jugadoresActuales);

    for (Jugador item : mesa) {
        System.out.println(item.getNombre());
    }
}

}
```